# CodedOutputStream .flush() causes Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, outputstream

I can write bytes to my coded output stream, but I cannot flush the stream. I have not closed it at any point and when I call socket.isConnected on the stream after encountering this error the socket returns true. Why could this be happening?

I have tried writing the byte array in multiple different ways and calling keepAlive() on the socket in efforts to force the streams to stay open.

```
            byte[] fullMessage = //contents of my array
            System.out.println("SENDING");
            os = CodedOutputStream.newInstance(ss.getOutputStream());
            for(int i = 0; i < fullMessage.length; i++){
                os.write(fullMessage[i]);
                //System.out.println("SPACE LEFT: " + os.spaceLeft());
            }
            System.out.println("SIZE OF SENT MESSSAGE: " + os.getTotalBytesWritten());
            System.out.println("FLUSHING");
            try{
                System.out.println("CONNECTED?: "+ss.isConnected());
                os.flush();
                ss.getOutputStream().flush(); //ss is my socket
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
```

Expected result should be a flush with no messages, always yields:
Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Comment: You will have to provide some information on your peer to determine why it is doesn't like what you're doing.

Comment: Also, when asking questions about why you're getting an exception please include a full stacktrace of the exception in the question.